# Set Global Database Connection for SQL chunk in Rnotebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

Is there a way to set a global database connection in a Rnotebook so you don't have to set the database connection for each SQL chunk?

Currently I have to set it as follows for each SQL chunk:

````
```{sql connection = my_connection}
select * from my_table
```
````

I would like to just be able to do the following:

````
```{sql}
select * from my_table
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Rmarkdown docs](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html#sql):

> *Setting a Default Connection*
>
> If you have many SQL chunks, it may be helpful to set a default for the connection chunk option in the setup chunk, so that it is not necessary to specify the connection on each individual chunk. You can do this as follows:
>
> ````
> ```{r setup}
> library(DBI)
> db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "sql.sqlite")
> knitr::opts_chunk$set(connection = "db")
> ```
> ````

So, in your example, set a hook with

````
```{r setup}
# insert your my_connection declaration here
knitr::opts_chunk$set(connection = "my_connection")
```
````

and put that chunk before all other chunks.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to work in Rnotebooks although they are just rmarkdown documents. Have tried it in an Rnotebook?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked ok. Can you give a bit more code we can see? Are you sure you're putting the "my_connection" in quotes and not sending the object?

Comment: Yes, I did put the connection in quotes. It is weird. Here is more of a sample.

Comment: Yes, I did put the connection in quotes. It is weird. Here is more of a sample. 
`
```{r connections}

my_conn = dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MY_SERVER;Database=MY_DB;Trusted_connection=true;")


knitr::opts_chunk$set(connection="my_conn")
```
`


```{sql}

select top 10 * from information_schema.columns

```

This returns: 

Error in (function (sql, outputFile, options)  : 
  The 'connection' option (DBI connection) is required for sql chunks.
Failed to execute SQL chunk

Comment: Sorry. The formatting didn't come out as I expected.

Comment: I don't know what might be the problem. Can you check if [this basic notebook](https://gist.github.com/Blaza/1b8089ebf701f37facedf00b87df23ca) works? It runs without a problem on my RStudio (I use RSQLite package to get a sample database)

Comment: Will check it when I get back from feeding the kids.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of what is going on. I use my Rnotebooks as an IDE instead of using the source screen. So I will run each chunk of a Rnotebook independently instead of all at once as part of a knit. It looks like the default connection will work when you knit but not when you run chunk by chunk. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes it does. However, when I renamed the chunk where we set up the connection from "connections" to "setup", it worked for me even chunk by chunk, as I had "Run Setup Chunk Automatically" checked in RStudio (under Run menu). I updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Blaza/1b8089ebf701f37facedf00b87df23ca) above to reflect that. Perhaps this solves it.

Comment: That worked!!!! You have to name the r chuck "setup" and it works!! Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: This works. However, when you add a sql chunk through the **Insert** option in Rstudio it looks like this: \`\`\`{sql connection=}\`\`\` so you have to either remove the connection part or add the connection name. I've put in a feature request at the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

this works. But when I insert a SQL chunk, the default is:

````
```{sql connection=}

```
````

instead of :

````
```{sql}

```
````

which means I need to add connection name or delete " connection=". How do I let it insert either:

````
```{sql connection="con"}

```
````

or:

````
```{sql}

```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).